# "sh: 1: react-scripts: not found" after running "npm run build"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, azure-web-app-service, nvm

Having some issues with running a Azure Static Web App that I have cloned from GitHub. Trying to follow these instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/local-development. I get the error: `sh: 1: react-scripts: not found` after running `npm run build`.

In the main project folder I ran this:

```
npm install -g @azure/static-web-apps-cli
```

```
added 198 packages, and audited 199 packages in 31s

32 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Ran:

```
npm run build
```

```
> hello@0.1.0 build
> react-scripts build

sh: 1: react-scripts: not found
```

What does "sh: 1: react-scripts: not found mean"? How can I fix it?

```
npm --version
8.1.0

node --version
v16.13.0

nvm --version
0.39.0

node --version
v16.13.0
```

(I realize that I probably haven't included all necessary information to understand the problem, so please tell me what more you need to know.)

Comment: It means `react-scripts` isn't installed locally or globally. Do you see it in your `package.json` and/or `node_modules/`?

Comment: You should probably also run `npm i`.

Comment: When I open ```packge.json```  I don't see ```react-scripts``` written. Under ```start``` (in ```package.json```) I see ```start```and ```test``` (under ```scripts```). Don't see any ```node_modules/``` folder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After running `npm i` everything workred out fine and I was able to run the app. Thanks to @AKX :)